# UIBarButtonItem text right-aligned when using possibleTitles?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I created a UIBarButton Item and set the title and everything works as expected. However, the button can have different titles depending on the state and resizes based on the title. To avoid this resizing, I use possibleTitles so that it will size it based on the largest title, but now all of the text is right-aligned.

I can fix this easily enough by using an offset specific to each title, but when I start getting into localization it becomes a little bit too much. Is there a way to keep the text centered when using possibleTitles?

Comment: Instead of making a bar button item with a title, you can use any UIView. In your case, you could use a UIButton.  Then you can customize the text and layout much more.

Comment: That isn't answering my original question though. I know that I can use a UIButton, but I want to know why this is occurring and how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

How about resize the rect instead of aligning text.
To do this, you might be able use these methods.

```
  - (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size
                         options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options 
                      attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes 
                         context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
  - (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size
                         options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options 
                         context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

These returns the rect that the text need.
And fix the UIBarButtonItem size.